# Using IF statement in MySQL and further calculation useing the result of the statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have an issue. I am trying to use IF statement in my SQL query and them use the result of this statement in further calculations:

```
SELECT average_rating, number_of_ratings,    
    IF(number_of_ratings < 500 AND number_of_ratings > 100, 0.90, 
        IF(number_of_ratings>=500 AND number_of_ratings<=1000, 0.95, 
            IF(number_of_ratings>1000, 0.99, 0.80)
        )
    ) AS rating_factor,    
    ROUND((rating_factor * average_rating), 4) AS factored_rating    
FROM table
ORDER by factored_rating DESC
```

However, it doesn't work and returns an error: **Unknown column 'rating_factor' in 'field list'**

Does anybody has an idea how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't reference an aliased column in the same statement. You'll need to write a sub-query

Comment: His usage wasn't that complicated.

Comment: As an aside a `CASE` statement instead of nested IFs would make it easier to read IMHO

Comment: @Conrad Disagree. What in the nested IF makes it harder to read?

Comment: @Richard I find that the TRUE part being a literal and the FALSE part being an arbitrarily long expression hard to read and easy to mess up (and reverse). I also find it hard to insert a new case. But that's just an opinion, not something I can say is factually true. Also as another aside its nice to see you back.

Comment: @Conrad heh :) so someone does remember me. My answer below lines up the IFs a bit better, not to say the author's was any harder to read. Much more concise than CASE even if it's MySQL specific, although Oracle has DECODE. Nice to see you too

Comment: @Richard I still find it to easy to do something wacky like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e52/6 but good formatting and ordering of the statements do indeed make it a non-issue

Answer (score 3):

Alain's query will work if you don't need BOTH the rating_factor and the factored_rating columns.  njk's query is an ANSI compliant version of subquerying.

However, since you're using **MySQL**, you can store values using temporary variables. I have also simplified your IF conditions.

```
SELECT
    average_rating,
    number_of_ratings,
    @x := IF(number_of_ratings> 1000, 0.99,
          IF(number_of_ratings>=500 , 0.95,
          IF(number_of_ratings> 100 , 0.90,
                                      0.80))) rating_factor,
    ROUND((@x * average_rating), 4) AS factored_rating
FROM mytable
ORDER by factored_rating DESC
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e52/1/0) to show this query.
For posterity, the sample is replicated below.

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable (
average_rating int,
number_of_ratings int,
factored_rating int);
insert into mytable
select 5,2,3 union all
select 4,1,5 union all
select 12,3,1 union all
select 11,4,2 union all
select 8,2,12;
```

Result of the query

```
"average_rating";"number_of_ratings";"rating_factor";"factored_rating"
"12";"3";"0.80";"9.6000"
"11";"4";"0.80";"8.8000"
"8";"2";"0.80";"6.4000"
"5";"2";"0.80";"4.0000"
"4";"1";"0.80";"3.2000"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
SELECT a.average_rating, a.number_of_ratings, ROUND((a.rating_factor * a.average_rating), 4) AS factored_rating
FROM
    (SELECT average_rating, number_of_ratings,    
        IF(number_of_ratings < 500 AND number_of_ratings > 100, 0.90, 
            IF(number_of_ratings>=500 AND number_of_ratings<=1000, 0.95, 
                IF(number_of_ratings>1000, 0.99, 0.80)
            )
        ) AS rating_factor   
    FROM table
    ORDER by factored_rating DESC) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of the `IF` statement in your formula.  I think I got the parens right, but you should see the idea:

```
SELECT average_rating, number_of_ratings,    
  ROUND((
    IF(number_of_ratings < 500 AND number_of_ratings > 100, 0.90, 
        IF(number_of_ratings>=500 AND number_of_ratings<=1000, 0.95, 
            IF(number_of_ratings>1000, 0.99, 0.80)
        )
    ) * average_rating), 4) as factored_rating    
FROM table
ORDER by factored_rating DESC
```